# Null hashmap value in Watcher

Tags: java, hashmap, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-watcher

I have 2 hashmap objects, `ctx.vars.hashOld` and `ctx.vars.hashNew` containing:

> {(agg_ecpm_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=7918041, (multikey_lift_history AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=32306281, (agg_dmm_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=39292548, (agg_dmm_daily_prt_20201129_20201205 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=6065195, (dim_global_multikey_lookup_history AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=79897376, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201101_20201107 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=20613344, (traceability_line_item_prt_20210103_20210109 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=29406842, (rtap_agg_pacing_health AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=18532079, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201213_20201219 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=25817110, (agg_trafficscope_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=18463490, (traceability_line_item_prt_20201227_20210102 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=38672393, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201206_20201212 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=26292726, (agg_dmm_daily_prt_20201108_20201114 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=5677117, (traceability_io_prt_20210103_20210109 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=11932531, (agg_settings_model_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=3690857, (dim_company_multikey_lookup_history AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=52817881, (agg_stats_new_metrics AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=1312744, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201220_20201226 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=25207340, (agg_stats_daily AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=1930913, (rtap_agg_pacing_health AND anly_stage AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=946000, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201108_20201114 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=22141144, (traceability_line_item_prt_20201220_20201226 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=38034899, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=17349196, (agg_dmm_daily_prt_20201122_20201128 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=6195309, (traceability_io_prt_20201227_20210102 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=15908106, (traceability_io_prt_20201220_20201226 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=16732576}

> {(agg_dmm_daily_prt_20201122_20201128 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=6215465, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=17935050, (dim_global_multikey_lookup_history AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=82151687, (agg_dmm_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=42790683, (traceability_io_prt_20201220_20201226 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=15834156, (agg_ecpm_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=8532763, (agg_dmm_daily_prt_20201108_20201114 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=5682918, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201220_20201226 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=23179579, (traceability_line_item_prt_20210110_20210116 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=6030912, (traceability_line_item_prt_20210103_20210109 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=30413191, (agg_settings_model_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=4302495, (agg_trafficscope_hourly_prt_20210103_20210109 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=23497940, (agg_dmm_hourly_prt_20210110_20210116 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=8878420, (agg_stats_daily AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=1942286, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201206_20201212 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=24699429, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201101_20201107 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=20613344, (agg_stats_new_metrics AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=1487951, (multikey_lift_history AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=33413054, (dim_company_multikey_lookup_history AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=57462519, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201108_20201114 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=22081784, (traceability_io_prt_20210103_20210109 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=12327906, (agg_dmm_daily_prt_20201129_20201205 AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=6072952, (rtap_agg_pacing_health AND anly_prod AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=18430105, (traceability_line_item_prt_20201220_20201226 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=38564796, (traceability_io_prt_20201227_20210102 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=14163152, (traceability_line_item_prt_20201227_20210102 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=34909797, (traceability_stats_hourly_prt_20201213_20201219 AND ops_ma AND anly_prod_db AND anly_prod)=23921212}

respectively. They contain the same keys but have different values. I am trying to calculate the differences between values for the same key but get `null` values when using the key of one object as the input to getting the value of the other object:

```
Map mapNew = ctx.vars.hashNew;
Map mapOld = ctx.vars.hashOld;
def test = [];
for (def key : mapNew.keySet()){
  def valNew = mapNew.get(key);
  def valOld = mapOld.get(key);
  test.add([valOld, valNew]);
}
```

And I'll get something like this in `test`:

> {0=[null, 18430105], 1=[null, 6030912], 2=[null, 6215465], 3=[null, 17935050], 4=[null, 23497940], 5=[null, 23179579], 6=[null, 15834156], 7=[null, 6072952], 8=[null, 42790683], 9=[null, 57462519], 10=[null, 82151687], 11=[null, 1487951], 12=[null, 14163152], 13=[null, 30413191], 14=[null, 22081784], 15=[null, 1942286], 16=[null, 33413054], 17=[null, 12327906], 18=[null, 23921212], 19=[null, 5682918], 20=[null, 38564796], 21=[null, 34909797], 22=[null, 20613344], 23=[null, 4302495], 24=[null, 24699429], 25=[null, 8878420], 26=[null, 8532763]}

Even though `mapOld` certainly has the same keys that `mapNew` has. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

**UPDATE** I was actually passing a StringBuilder object into the key. Changed to string type using `toString()`. In addition to this, instead of using the keys from `keySet()`, I put those into a separate list of strings and used that instead and I'm now seeing desired results.

Comment: What type of key is there?

Comment: Key is just a string of format "(...)" where ... is just some identifiers separated by AND for other purposes

Comment: Ye so I think it's reference type so you pass such a different object (in memory) to .get() method, try to do it like String.valueOf() or wrap String to another class and implement equals and hashCode, then your keys will be compared by value not by reference.

Comment: Do you mean to try instead of `mapOld.get(key)`, try `mapOld.get(String.valueOf(key))`?

Comment: Maybe that will help in some way I'm not sure :D

Comment: Didn't have any luck :/